# How to derive a ViewModel for an object attribute in another ViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I want to get a ViewModel for an attribute of another object held in another ViewModel.

I have this relationship: In a house there are multiple people. (A 1:n relationship where people are encoded in the Houses table, rather than using a join table.) I have a problem in this scenario:
An existing House is to be shown in HouseDetailsActivity, which contains a HouseDetailsFragment and a PeopleListFragment. The HouseDetailsActivity gets the HouseViewModel in onCreate, like this:

```
houseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new HouseViewModel.Factory(getApplication(), id)).get(HouseViewModel.class);
```

The HouseViewModel is able to return LiveData, as it gets the HouseEntity from the database. The PeopleListFragment needs to get LiveData for the list of people for that house from somewhere, but should not need knowledge of any view model other than PeopleListViewModel. So, also in the HouseDetailsActivity onCreate, I get a PeopleListViewModel, like this:

```
peopleListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PeopleListViewModel.class);
```

that I expect can be shared with the PeopleListFragment, getting it like this:

```
peopleViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(PeopleListViewModel.class);
```

The problem is how to get the list of people in LiveData into the ViewModel. The list of people in the HouseEntity inside the HouseDetailsActivity (HouseDetailsViewModel) is not LiveData. (I want to be able to see the list of people from the HouseEntity in the PeopleListFragment via a PeopleListViewModel.)

I've seen the documentation for MediatorLiveData, which I don't think applies here, because ultimately there is only 1 source of the PeopleList.

```
public class HouseDetailsActivity
{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    houseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new HouseViewModel.Factory(getApplication(), id)).get(HouseViewModel.class);
    peopleListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PeopleListViewModel.class);
    /* This can't be done, because the HouseEntity may not yet be loaded to the ViewModel. ie. NullPointerException here
    List<Person> people = m_houseViewModel.getHouse().getPeopleList();
    peopleListViewModel.setPeople(people);
    */
}
}

@Entity(tableName="houses")
public class HouseEntity implements MutableHouse
{
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name="hid")
    public int id = 0;

    @ColumnInfo(name="address")
    private String address = null;

    /** This is the encoded people, for multiple in a single database field. */
    @ColumnInfo(name="residents")
    private String residents = null;

    public List<Person> getPeopleList ()
    { return HouseEncoding.decodePeople(getResidents()); }
    ...
}

public class HouseViewModel
{
    private final int houseId;
    private MutableLiveData<HouseEntity> house; // The list of people is inside house here, but not as LiveData

    public LiveData<HouseEntity> getObservableHouse ()
    { return house; }

    HouseViewModel (@NonNull Application application, int houseId)
    {
        super(application);
        this.houseId = houseId;
        this.house = getRepository().getHouseObservable(houseId);
    }

    /**
     * A creator is used to inject the house ID into the ViewModel
     */
    public static class Factory extends ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory
    {
        @NonNull
        private Application application;
        private int houseId;

        public Factory (@NonNull Application application, int houseId)
        {
            this.application = application;
            this.houseId = houseId;
        }

        @Override
        @NonNull
        public <T extends ViewModel> T create (@NonNull Class<T> modelClass)
        {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (T) new HouseViewModel(application, houseId);
        }
    }
}

public class PeopleListViewModel
{
    private MutableLiveData<List<Person>> people;

    void setPeople (List<Person> people)
    { this.people.setValue(people); }
    ...
}
```

Within the PeopleListFragment:

```
private void observerSetup ()
{
    peopleViewModel.getPeople().observe(this, people -> {
        adapter.setPeople(people); // for RecyclerView
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have initialized these two viewmodels differently.

> houseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new HouseViewModel.Factory(getApplication(), id)).get(HouseViewModel.class);
>
> peopleListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PeopleListViewModel.class);

Just change:

> houseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new HouseViewModel.Factory(getApplication(), id)).get(HouseViewModel.class);

to this:

> houseViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HouseViewModel.class);

You can initialize two viewmdoels in a view. Don't be shy about it.

Comment: I can't do what you suggest. What I have done is to inject the house id into the HouseViewModel in what i believe is a normal way

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense to achieve your object "in what is a normal way". See here as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/3259429/4209724

Comment: I meant the normal way to inject an id for the ViewModel to get the observable object (HouseEntity) from the repository/database. I've added the constructor and Factory code used to do that. I saw the post you refer to when I was researching my issue. The difference is that the collection (List<Person>) I am wanting in the PeopleListViewModel is not Observable in the HouseViewModel.